# In what way does the page rotation influence a given form field in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, rotation

I am having a hard time understanding exactly what is expected per the PDF spec regarding page vs form field rotations.

The simplest example is a PDF with a single Page with a single textbox form field in the very center with some default text. Without messing with anything else, we see the text read horizontally.

If we change the Page rotation to 90, would it be expected that the text is now vertical and sideways?

If we leave the Page rotation at 90 and then set the textbox's rotation to 90, would it be expected that the text is now upside down?

I have the second situation in a PDF I'm working with currently (which I can't share) and I see the text appear as if the Page and textbox rotations were 0. Obviously that must be correct if that's what Acrobat and other PDF readers show but if someone could explain a little why that's the case it would be much appreciated!

Comment: It depends on the flags set in the widget annotation. Look up the NoRotate flag in the specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Form fields are represented on the page with a Widget type annotation.

To have a text field appear right side up, the Widget annotation should have the same Rotate value as the page.

This also applies to FreeText annotations, which are common markup to add to a PDF in a viewer. Typically the annotation's Rotate value equals the sum of the Page rotation, and any current rotation applied to the PDF viewer. So if a page has a rotation of 90, and in a PDF viewer the user rotates the page 90 degrees more, and adds a FreeText annotation, then the Rotate entry would be 180, and this would result in the text being right side up at the time they add the annotation (but rotated if they undo the viewer rotation).

> If we leave the Page rotation at 90 and then set the textbox's
>   rotation to 90, would it be expected that the text is now upside down?

No, the text of the form field would be look "correct" and in normal reading orientation. The appearance/rotation of text inside the annotation is independent of the page rotation.

What could also clarify things for you, is to understand that annotations have two parts; metadata describing their state and appearance settings, and an Optional appearance stream that explicitly describes the appearance. The Rotate entry is part of the metadata, and when an appearance stream is generated for annotations like a Text Field this value is used to rotate the appearance. The appearance of the annotation is otherwise completely independent from any page rotation, and as described above this is on purpose so annotations can rotate independently (maybe you want the text to be side ways).